# I want to implement Facebook login in my cordova app

Tags: cordova

I am using https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin but i can't implement login with facebook.

How can i implement it?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. To receive help you need to show us some code and describe what you've tried so far.

Comment: I am getting the error facebookConnectPlugin is not defined on facebookConnectPlugin.login(Array strings of permissions, Function success, Function failure).

Answer (score 0):

First you need to clone the git repository of the plugin, then install the plugin using the Cordova CLI as described in the install guide (Android): https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/blob/master/platforms/android/README.md

```
git clone https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin.git
cordova -d plugin add /path/to/cloned/phonegap-facebook-plugin --variable APP_ID="123456789" --variable APP_NAME="myApplication"
```

Also, you need to include the JavaScript file of this plugin, as can be seen in their example: https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/blob/master/platforms/android/assets/www/index.html

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/facebookConnectPlugin.js"></script>
```